# Does assigning a JSON object to the style attribute in ReactJS make the object non-configurable

Tags: json, reactjs, attributes, styles, configurable

I am trying to dynamically change css styles in my ReactJS application using the "style" attribute. Typically, I assign the attribute to a JSON object, and when I want modify the style attribute based off of a state change in my component. I re-assign the entire JSON object as shown below.

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      myStyle: {
        marginTop: "100px",
        background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.85)",
        boxShadow: "0px 5px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      }
    };
  }

  changeStyleFunction() {
    this.setState({
      myStyle: {
        marginTop: "0px",
        background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.85)",
        boxShadow: "0px 5px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={myStyle}>
        <button onClick={this.changeStyleFunction.bind(this)}/>
        //some content here
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This works fine, but if I have a JSON object that is 15+ elements, this process turns into a lot of extra code to modify one property. So I decided to take my style object out of the component's state, and use dot notation to modify it as shown below.

```
let myStyle = {
  marginTop: "100px",
  background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.85)",
  boxShadow: "0px 5px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1)",
};

export default class MyClass extends React.Component {

  changeStyleFunction() {
    myStyle.marginTop = "0px"
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={myStyle}>
        <button onClick={this.changeStyleFunction.bind(this)}/>
        //some content here
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'marginTop' of object '#<Object>'
```

So I tried to use `Object.defineProperty(myStyle, 'marginTop', {writable: true})` to see if I could force the object to be writable. This only produced another error as shown below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: marginTop
```

This only occurs if the object is assigned to the style attribute, which leads me to believe that the underlying ReactJS framework sets the JSON object to be non-configurable if it is assigned to the style attribute. Am I correct? And, how do I circumnavigate this in the future to avoid rewriting large JSON objects in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that you should not try to mutate the `style` object directly.

You can modify just one property by spreading the current styles and just changing the one you want to change.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7x61mynzq))**

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myStyle: {
      marginTop: "100px",
      background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.85)",
      boxShadow: "0px 5px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1)"
    }
  };

  changeStyleFunction() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return {
        myStyle: { ...previousState.myStyle, marginTop: "0px" }
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.myStyle}>
        <button onClick={this.changeStyleFunction.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```